# Where does the extra blood in arterial circulation when exercising come from?

Tags: hematology, exercise

When exercising more blood is in our arterial circulation. 
Where did this blood come from and how did it get there ?

Comment: http://health.howstuffworks.com/wellness/diet-fitness/exercise/sports-physiology8.htm

Comment: Please do some googling before asking here.

Answer (score 3):

Contraction of muscles presses on the veins and increases venous pressure, which increases blood return to the heart and therefore increases cardiac output via the [Frank-Starling mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frank%E2%80%93Starling_law).

Importantly, the **total volume of blood in the body does not change** by this mechanism, though the amount in the arteries can increase because there is less blood in the veins.

That part of the story is just a minor contributor, though. The more substantial circulatory adaptations to exercise involve the *flow rate* to muscles. More blood gets to the muscles because heart rate increases, vessels in the active muscles dilate, and vessels in the gut constrict. None of these mechanisms change the amount of blood in circulation, they only change the *flow rate in the muscles*.

Answer (score 0):

**The splanchnic circulation serves as a reservoir for blood**.  The splanchnic circulation consists of visceral and digestive organs.  Blood can be mobilized from these organs out to the muscles in time of need.

from http://anesthesiology.pubs.asahq.org/article.aspx?articleid=1943356

[image: diagram of splanchnic circulation]

I think of this as blood's regular job, helping move nutrients around, dropping them off in the liver.  Peacetime work.  When it is time to mobilize, blood moves out of these organs and into the periphery where the muscles can get it.

same source

> The Splanchnic Blood Reservoir Normovolemic healthy male adults have a
>   blood volume of approximately 70 ml/kg body weight. Splanchnic organs
>   constitute 10% of the body weight, but they contain 25% of the total
>   blood volume. 1,6 Nearly two thirds of the splanchnic blood (i.e.  , >
>   800 ml) can be autotransfused into the systemic circulation within
>   seconds (table 2). The liver and intestines each provide between 300
>   and 400 ml of the blood; the spleen only contributes approximately 100
>   ml, but the hematocrit of this blood often approaches 75%. Therefore,
>   the splanchnic vasculature serves as an important blood reservoir for
>   the circulatory system.

Other animals can mobilize more from their splanchnic beds.  Humans do mobilize blood from the spleen but dogs have contractile spleens that can actually squeeze blood out into the circulation when the muscles need it.

Comment: I sure don't understand the down vote.  Isn't this a good answer for the bio stack?

Comment: Not the down voter. Asking for reasons for down votes is unlikely to get you any answers for two reasons: 1) people are reluctant to give explanations for them and 2) even worse, when someone (like me) comes along and explains why it might have happened, they get blamed for the down vote and nasty comments ensue. Two reasons are enough, but there are more.